# Is it possible to point my DNS record to the same IP address as another domain?

Tags: domains, dns, dynamic, dynamic-dns

I recently bought a domain from Europe Registry for 1€.
And I'm hosting a Server at home that needs to be reachable from the internet, which if done so previously through a domain provided by the router producer which is a long hashed link but it always points to the dynamic ip.
Is it possible to point the Eu. Reg. domain to the same address as the dynamic domain outside of that zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the following:

1. The router has a domain name associated with it.
2. The router-provided domain name is publicly accessible.
3. The router can port forward requests.

In that case, you can add a CNAME record to a **sub domain** (www, for example) of your new domain name. The value should be the router domain name.

Note: CNAME cannot be created for the root domain. Hence, you should be accessing your local server via a subdomain of your new domain.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I couldn't for the live of me find an answer but this was surprisingly easy.

Comment: A number of larger hosts now support [CNAME Flattening](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/) which allows you to add a CNAME record for the root domain.

Comment: Interesting information. It seems that the response for a flattened CNAME will be an A record (processed internally). So If I am right, the OP can use the feature provided he uses a DNS host that supports CNAME flattening. Am I right?

Comment: So, what I did was add www as CNAME to the other domain and when opening the root domain it automatically redirects to www.example.xyz. It also has an A record for the root domain that I reverted to the address it originally pointed at. I didn't find an option for CNAME flattening though

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can point an "infinite" amount of names to one IP address.

Which is exactly how mass virtual hosting is working (there are far more websites hostnames than there are IPv4 addresses available to webhosting companies).

Comment: I think they're asking how they would do that. Especially how it would work so that it points to the same IP address even when the other domain changes its IP address due to dynamic DNS.